# Why is my unity crashing while I am testing my game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game through Unity. I used to be with Unreal Engine but it did not really suit my pc so I got that instead. I have visited the Unity website and created a dump file for unity.exe but my project seems to crash all the time when I press play.

Is there any way someone can try to help me?

I have:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
16GB RAM
Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600

Comment: Show us your error messages. What is crashing?

Comment: Please also provide details of your HDD/SSD, RAM model and Unity version.  
For hardware problems, check if your PC meets the minimum requirements for running Unity. Check if there are driver updates available for  your hardware.  
For software problems, check if your problem is a known bug. If not report it.

Answer (score 0):

99% chance your integrated GPU Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 cannot handle Unity.

This used to happen often on my AMD Radeon R7-240, even though it is better than Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600.

See:
https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-HD-4600-Mobile-115-GHz-vs-AMD-R7-240/m7676vsm8608

If such is the case, I would recommend getting a dedicated GPU or downgrading to an older version of Unity.

Comment: This happens to me on both a 2070 super and 3080ti so my guess is it has more to do with app construction (half-hazard use of async/await or messy shader code).